# Start ServerManager in Windows Server Core

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-core

I created an ECS instance in alibabacloud with Windows Server Core 1903.

I want to start the IIS server manager GUI, and I am used to do this by simply running `ServerManager` command in powershell.

Here however, the command isn't recognized, even if the `Web-Mgmt-Tools` feature is installed :

[image]

**How can I start the server manager GUI?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ServerManager is not included in Windows Server Core [1903]. Just enable WinRM, start the ServerManager on your local Machine and connect to the new core host. That is how it is meant to be managed anyway.